# google maps close marker when click on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I spent my whole day trying to figure out, what am I doing wrong.

I have a google map and after a user search, several markers appear on the map. Every marker when clicked pops an infobox. I used infobubble.js for that. Every bubble has a close button that works perfectly. The thing i want to do is when I click the map, the open infobubble to be closed.

A small fragment of my code is like this
For every marker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });  

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(map,'click',func(){
              infoWindow.close();
});


          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, ib,html);
```

one of my tries is this code. I tried several things but nothing worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ib` is the instance of the infobubble, try `ib.close();` instead.